# Show null values while joining SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Stuck on this assignment and its not displaying null values as it should.

Instructions:

> List the number of transactions handled by each department. Include
>   departments that have not handled any transactions. Show your results 
>   in ascending order on department.

This is what I have so far and it displays the total transactions for departments with transaction and skips the null values.

```
SELECT 
    PC.Department, 
    COUNT(TD.TransactionID) AS TotalTransactions
FROM 
    TRANSACTION_DETAILS TD
INNER JOIN 
    PRODUCTS P ON P.ItemCode = TD.ItemCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    PRODUCT_CATEGORIES PC ON P.Category = PC.Category
GROUP BY 
    PC.Department
ORDER BY 
    PC.Department ASC
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a department table in your query?

Comment: no the DB doesn't have one of those. i have the correct tables (i'm pretty sure) its just not displaying the NULL values even though i have the left outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT      PC.Department, COUNT(TD.TransactionID) AS TotalTransactions
FROM        PRODUCT_CATEGORIES  PC 
LEFT JOIN   PRODUCTS            P   ON P.Category = PC.Category
LEFT JOIN   TRANSACTION_DETAILS TD  ON P.ItemCode = TD.ItemCode
GROUP BY    PC.Department
ORDER BY    PC.Department ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need  also department without value you need  left join  starting PRODUCT_CATEGORIES  ( Department)

```
  SELECT PC.Department, COUNT(TD.TransactionID) AS TotalTransactions
  FROM PRODUCT_CATEGORIES PC
  LEFT  JOIN PRODUCTS P ON P.Category = PC.Category
  LEFT  JOIN TRANSACTION_DETAILS TD ON P.ItemCode = TD.ItemCode
  GROUP BY PC.Department
  ORDER BY PC.Department ASC
```

Comment: query will fail due to duplicate PC alias